# How can I use dataset with cloneelement?

Tags: reactjs

How can I set a data attribute on an element when using cloneelement?

I've tried it this way.

```
const clonedItem = React.cloneElement(item, {
    dataset: { "data-test": 123 },
    dataTest: 123,
})
```

But that doesn't set any attribute in my html...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you have an example of the code? This question looks a bit like a XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I think my question is very precise, more code is not necessary. So it's not XY problem... I'm prototyping with www.framer.com. I need to know the index of the element inside a grid. And setting an attribute is the easiest and quickest way.

Comment: Looks like you've got your answer - just can't see why you would need to use `React.cloneElement` so wanted to understand what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are storing a custom component in `item` variable i.e

`let item = <ItemComponent />`.

Just  store html element in `item` variable i.e

```
let item = <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
```

And that will set attribute in `div` element.

If you use custom component, you need to use the props passed in the component.

i.e `ItemComponent` will be as

```
function ItemComponent({dataTest}){
   return (
    <div dataTest={dataTest}>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The one that worked for me is by settings the key as string

```
const clonedItem = React.cloneElement(item, {
    'data-test': 123
})
```